# "All Sites" grid overview doesn't reorganize when an expanded item is collapsed after a tab change

Tags: bug, design, homepage

**First step** Click on an item to expand it like on the picture below, for example Meta:

[image]

---

**Second step** Change the tab, where this item will still be listed, like on the picture below, for example Technology:

[image]

---

**Last step** Click aside to collapse the item, like on the picture below.

[image]

---

The other items are not reorganized to fill the hole that the expanded item leaves.

I tried on Chrome and Firefox.